# mosquitto_pub command in python code not executing in crontab

Tags: python-2.7, mosquitto

I'm working with Linux Debian, Mosquitto 1.3.5 and a Python 2.7.9 script.

If I run the Python script in the terminal (using the same command I wrote in the crontab), the mosquitto_pub command will run. But it doesn't execute using the following cron:

```
2,12,22,32,42,52 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/user/ma.py
```

The cron will start the script and will execute the first part of the script (writing some data to a csv file), but not the mosquitto_pub command.

Part of my Python script:

```
liv = str(190 + float(parser.data[157]))
    try:
        ssl = '/home/user/file.pem'
        base = "mosquitto_pub -h host -p 8883 -t measures -q 2 --cafile " + ssl
        epoch = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
        delta = datetime.strptime(dttime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") - epoch
        ds = delta.total_seconds()
        mqttStr = base + " -m 'FILE_LL," + str(int(ds)) + ',' + liv + "'"
        subprocess.Popen(mqttStr, shell=True)
    except:
        print "It was not possible to send your data via mqtt.", sys.exc_info()[0], datetime.utcnow()
```

I tried with os.system, subprocess.call and subprocess.Popen, but the command doesn't start.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The documentation page misses one step for Ubuntu:

`sudo apt-get install mosquitto-clients` 
to use `mosquitto_pub` and `mosquitto_sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I solved the issue.I had to use the full path to mosquitto_pub:

```
/usr/local/bin/mosquitto_pub
```